# Search result does not move to the first column in the website - HTML5 search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image-gallery

I am doing my a photo gallery with a lot of photo and i would like to use sorting function and the search function. The sorting function work fine, however, the search function doesnt.

I still can search, but the result do not go to the first column but stay in the original place which confuse ppl since there a lot of empty space. you can only scroll down to see what is left.

I have tried alot of template online and only this works.

this is the layout:

[image: layout]

this is the result of sorting, you can see only 2 pic left and it move under the search bar

[image: result of sorting]

this is the result of searching, you can see only 1 pic left and its stay in the original position and do not move under the search bar.

[image: result of searching]

```
      <script>
    function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    }
    </script>


<style>
.portfolio-items,
.portfolio-filter {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 -20px 20px 0;
}

.portfolio-filter > li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.portfolio-filter > li a.active {
    color: #FFF;
    background: #00645a;
    border: 2px solid #00645a;
}

.portfolio-items > li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.portfolio-items.col-2 > li {
    width: 50%;
}

.portfolio-items.col-3 > li {
    width: 33%;
}

.portfolio-items.col-4 > li {
    width: 25%;
}

.portfolio-items.col-5 > li {
    width: 20%;
}

.portfolio-items.col-6 > li {
    width: 16%;
}

.portfolio-item {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.portfolio-item .item-inner {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    position: relative;
}


.portfolio-item img {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.portfolio-item img:hover {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.portfolio-item h5 {

    background: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.portfolio-item:hover h5,
.team-member:hover .team-content,
.post:hover .content {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #00645a;
}

.portfolio-item h5:after {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-width: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.portfolio-item .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 300ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 300ms;
    transition: opacity 300ms;
}

.portfolio-item .overlay .preview {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.portfolio-item:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}


#myUL {

     list-style-type: none;

}

#myUL li a {

    display: block;

}

/* Start: Recommended Isotope styles */


/**** Isotope Filtering ****/

.isotope-item {
    z-index: 2;
}

.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 1;
}


/**** Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/

.isotope,
.isotope .isotope-item {
    -webkit-transition-duration: .8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: .8s;
    -ms-transition-duration: .8s;
    -o-transition-duration: .8s;
    transition-duration: .8s;
}

.isotope {
    -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
    -moz-transition-property: height, width;
    -ms-transition-property: height, width;
    -o-transition-property: height, width;
    transition-property: height, width;
}

.isotope .isotope-item {
    -webkit-transition-property: 0 opacity;
    -moz-transition-property: 0 opacity;
    -ms-transition-property: 0 opacity;
    -o-transition-property: 0 opacity;
    transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
</style>

<div id="content-wrapper">
        <section id="portfolio" class="white">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="gap"></div> 
                    <div class="center gap fade-down section-heading">
                        <h2 class="main-title">VIDEO</h2>
                        <hr>
                        <p>You can find all training video if you want to refresh your memory.</p>
                    </div> 
                    <ul class="portfolio-filter fade-down center">
                        <li><a class="btn btn-outlined btn-primary active" href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
                        <li><a class="btn btn-outlined btn-primary" href="#" data-filter=".h">Nature</a></li>
                        <li><a class="btn btn-outlined btn-primary" href="#" data-filter=".g">City</a></li>
                        <li><a class="btn btn-outlined btn-primary" href="#" data-filter=".f">Road</a></li>
                        <li><a class="btn btn-outlined btn-primary" href="#" data-filter=".e">Car</a></li>
                        <li><a class="btn btn-outlined btn-primary" href="#" data-filter=".d">Plane</a></li>
                        <li><a class="btn btn-outlined btn-primary" href="#" data-filter=".c">Train</a></li>
                        <li><a class="btn btn-outlined btn-primary" href="#" data-filter=".b">River</a></li>
                         <li><a class="btn btn-outlined btn-primary" href="#" data-filter=".a">Industrial</a></li>
                    </ul><!--/#portfolio-filter-->

                <div class="gap"></div> 
                <div class="search center animation bounce-in" ><span class="fa fa-search"></span><input id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" class="filtr-search" value="" placeholder="Your Search" data-search="" type="text"><p></p></div>
                <div class="gap"></div> 

                    <ul id="myUL" class="portfolio-items col-3 isotope fade-up">
                        <li class="portfolio-item isotope-item in access account">
                            <div class="item-inner">
                                <a class="preview" href="https://youtu.be/vLYzgGXhj44" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="images/video/city_1.jpg" alt="">
                                <h5 class="searchkeyword">Old town</h5></a>

                            </div>           
                        </li><!--/.portfolio-item-->
                        <li class="portfolio-item isotope-item incident a d g">
                            <div class="item-inner">
                                <a class="preview" href="https://youtu.be/qeLu68qXzps" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="images/video/city_2.jpg" alt="">
                                <h5 class="searchkeyword">Raining Sky</h5></a>

                            </div>           
                        </li><!--/.portfolio-item-->
                        <li class="portfolio-item isotope-item incident h b c">
                            <div class="item-inner">
                                <a class="preview" href="https://youtu.be/l7DVd3nwdaw" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="images/video/city_3.jpg" alt="">
                                <h5 class="searchkeyword">Sea</h5></a>

                            </div>           
                        </li><!--/.portfolio-item-->
                        <li class="portfolio-item isotope-item f g">
                            <div class="item-inner">
                                <a class="preview" href="https://youtu.be/5X354J5uTwg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="images/video/industrial_1.jpg" alt="">
                                <h5 class="searchkeyword">Galaxy</h5></a>

                            </div>           
                        </li><!--/.portfolio-item-->       

                      <li class="portfolio-item isotope-item incident e c a">
                            <div class="item-inner">
                                <a class="preview" href="https://youtu.be/ChJhXayrOL4" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="images/video/industrial_2.jpg" alt="">
                                <h5 class="searchkeyword">Industrial</h5></a>

                            </div>           
                        </li><!--/.portfolio-item-->
                       <li class="portfolio-item isotope-item a  c">
                            <div class="item-inner">
                                <a class="preview" href="https://youtu.be/55W3CXfqLIY" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="images/video/industrial_3.jpg" alt="">
                                <h5 class="searchkeyword">Highway</h5></a>

                            </div>           
                        </li><!--/.portfolio-item-->
                       <li class="portfolio-item isotope-item f b">
                            <div class="item-inner">
                                <a class="preview" href="https://youtu.be/XVnsgxuEZaA" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="images/video/nature_1.jpg" alt="">
                                <h5 class="searchkeyword">Bue River</h5></a>

                            </div>           
                        </li><!--/.portfolio-item-->
                       <li class="portfolio-item isotope-item h b">
                            <div class="item-inner">
                                <a class="preview" href="https://youtu.be/XULUBg_ZcAU" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="images/video/nature_2.jpg" alt="">
                                <h5 class="searchkeyword">City Night</h5></a>

                            </div>           
                        </li><!--/.portfolio-item-->
                       <li class="portfolio-item apps isotope-item b c">
                            <div class="item-inner">
                                <a class="preview" href="https://youtu.be/Rkkw8RhH9ck" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="images/video/nature_3.jpg" alt="">
                                <h5 class="searchkeyword">Flight to SFO</h5></a>

                            </div>           
                        </li><!--/.portfolio-item-->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide the css for either of these: portfolio-item isotope-item incident ...
Something may be affecting the li

Comment: I have added the css already, for those incident, a,b,c is just for data sorting and does not have css rules. thanks

Comment: the code works fine for me. I only changed the image urls. https://jsfiddle.net/ojqxt0u2/

Comment: i found out that this is something to prevent the result move under the search  bar, but i dont have enough knowledge to fix the problem, could you please help.

Comment: $(window).load(function(){
  'use strict';
  var portfolio_selectors = $('.portfolio-filter li a');
  if(portfolio_selectors!='undefined'){
    var portfolio = $('.portfolio-items');
    portfolio.isotope({
      itemSelector : 'li',
      layoutMode : 'fitRows'
    });
    portfolio_selectors.on('click', function(){
      portfolio_selectors.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
      portfolio.isotope({ filter: selector });
      return false;
    });
  }
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the isotope plugin you are using as it controls the layout of the `li`. You can do the filter with isotope so you dont have to do any other styling that interferes with isotope. This is what you can replace your script with:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';
    var portfolio_selectors = $('.portfolio-filter li a');
    var portfolio = $('.portfolio-items');

    if (portfolio_selectors != 'undefined') {
        portfolio.isotope({
            itemSelector: 'li',
            layoutMode: 'fitRows'
        });
        portfolio_selectors.on('click', function() {
            portfolio_selectors.removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            portfolio.isotope({
                filter: selector
            });
            return false;
        });
        var search = $('#myInput');
        $(search).on('keyup', function(e){
          var filter = e.target.value;

          // filter by name
          portfolio.isotope({ 
            itemSelector: 'li',
            filter: function() {
              var name = $(this).find('h5').text();
              var found = name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) > -1;
              return found;
          } })
        });
    }

});

</script>
```

You will have to remove `keyup="myFunction()`.

Comment: i have a problem now, sometime all the pic will merge together when loading that page. check here for the picture https://imgur.com/U9zXS9J  Not all the time i load the page. Also, once you click on the sorting button or type something to search, it will become normal, any idea??

Comment: When you hard reset, the plugin js are not loaded, so may be isotope doesnt create layout right away. To solve it, may be you can hide the whole block, and show it when the `$(document).ready` fires. It's just my guess

Comment: Thank you, let me try cause i am not familiar with javascript...still learning.......